# Does cron.yaml support conditions?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, cron

Is it possible to have conditions (`if` ... `else` ...) in GAE `cron.yaml`?
For ex., to have something like

`if app_identity.get_application_id() == 'my-appid'` then run the job.

Understand, that probably the same result I can have by implementing it in the job handler. Just interesting if it could be done within cron.yaml.

Comment: The documentation for cron.yaml is pretty complete.  Why would there be such complex behaviour or feature not documented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, that isn't possible.

The Cron.yaml page is only made for defining the jobs, not to code.

I'd recommend putting your logic inside of the job that you're calling, as you mentioned.

Hope this helps.